# is there any way to pass an arraylist from an onDataChange to a fragment ViewPagerAdapter inner Class?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

Don't know how to send the arraylist that's been filled in the onDataChanged to the method that's called to create a new fragment to pass it with a bundle object

i've tried messing with the constructor to expect it as a parameter and in the constructor's body appears as "not empty" but after that i don't know how to send it to the addFragment method since i've tried and seems "null".
i've tried to access to it as MainActivity.this.arraylist but it says is empty.
i've made it static and it still says it's empty

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TabLayout tablayout;
private ViewPager viewpager;

private Temperatura temperatura;
private Humedad humedad;
private Viento viento;
private Info informacion;

List<String> Lecturabundle = new ArrayList<>();

DatabaseReference mDatabase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    tablayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewpager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    temperatura = new Temperatura();
    humedad = new Humedad();
    viento = new Viento();
    informacion = new Info();

    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);


    ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 0);

    mDatabase.child("lectura").child("hora").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          Lecturabundle.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });



    viewpageradapter.addFragment(temperatura, "Temperatura");
    viewpageradapter.addFragment(humedad, "Humedad");
    viewpageradapter.addFragment(viento, "Viento");
    viewpageradapter.addFragment(informacion, "info");


    viewpager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);
}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String>  fragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();



    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title, List<String> recibeArrayList){
```

HERE'S WHERE I NEED LECTURABUNDLE TO BE SO I CAN SEND IT TO EACH FRAGMENT BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IT THE RIGHT WAY SINCE WHAT I'VE TRIED GETS ME TO A POINT WHERE WHEN IT'S FINALLY HERE ISEMPTY() SAYS TRU

```
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArrayList("recibe", (ArrayList<String>) Lecturabundle);
        fragment.setArguments(b);


        fragments.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitle.add(title);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitle.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

i need Lecturabundle to be in the addFragment so i can pass it as a bundle to the fragments

Comment: Your app will break in production. Check #3 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0

Comment: Thank you very much i'll redesign my app following those guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is using Bundle to pass it to your fragment.
But in your case, you are creating/initializing fragment in onCreate and the onDataChanged method gets called after some time you can say it may take a couple of seconds to minutes to get called depending on Data.
So if you want to send that data to your fragment what you can do is you can create a public method in your fragment class let's say name it as newDataInserted(list) with list as parameter. now you can call that method inside onDataChanged() using your fragment instance you created earlier.
For example

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      Lecturabundle.add(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
      if(temperature != null) {
         temperatura.newDataInserted(Lecturabundle);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i ended up calling the creation of the fragments inside the onDataChange so by the time the arraylist is finally full it's safe to use the arraylist anywhere, your understanding of the asynchrony helped me a lot

Comment: Great. If my answer helped you in any way just upvote it so others can get to it.